# Updating a shared property between objects

Tags: javascript

I have two objects that share a property `foo`.

```
let obj = {
  // ...
  foo: "ba",
  // ...
};
let obj2 = {
  // ...
  foo: obj.foo,
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way that by updating `obj.foo` or `obj2.foo` the other one would have the same value as the updated one? For example

```
obj.foo += "r"
console.log(obj2.foo); // "bar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the string in its own object, for example a one-element array.

```js
let obj = {
  // ...
  foo: ["ba"],
  // ...
};
let obj2 = {
  // ...
  foo: obj.foo,
  // ...
}

obj.foo[0] += "r"
console.log(obj2.foo[0]); // "bar"
```

Comment: It's not the answer i was hoping for but it works! And it works between scopes which is nice, even if the rest of my code needs a little rework now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) with a local variable that lies in the same scope.

```js
let foo = 'ba'

let obj = {
  // ...
  get foo() {
    return foo;
  },
  set foo(v) {
    foo = v;
  },
  // ...
};
let obj2 = {
  // ...
  get foo() {
    return foo;
  },
  set foo(v) {
    foo = v;
  },
  // ...
}

console.log(obj.foo, obj2.foo)
obj.foo += 'a'
console.log(obj.foo, obj2.foo)
obj2.foo = 'foobar'
console.log(obj.foo, obj2.foo)
```

Or you can keep getter and setter in second object and update property of first one within setter.

```js
let obj = {
  // ...
  foo: 'ba',
  // ...
};
let obj2 = {
  // ...
  get foo() {
    return obj.foo;
  },
  set foo(v) {
    obj.foo = v;
  },
  // ...
}

console.log(obj.foo, obj2.foo)
obj.foo += 'a'
console.log(obj.foo, obj2.foo)
obj2.foo = 'foobar'
console.log(obj.foo, obj2.foo)
```